# how to remove css from div when selecting another - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

Can somebody please help me?

I have an iron-list where each entry has a "settings" icon that, when clicked causes a panel to slide in from the right. The problem is that I would like the panel to close when I open another row's panel, but currently they all open and remain so unless I specifically close them myself.

I know that I am missing something in the JS for this, but I am not sure as to what. Something with a "when clickout of div, close" type situation.

Much appreciation for any help offered.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container horizontal layout">
    <paper-icon-button class="icons" icon="settings" on-click="toggleSettings"></paper-icon-button>
    <div id="edit" class="settings">
       <paper-icon-button icon="delete"></paper-icon-button>
       <paper-icon-button icon="create"></paper-icon-button>
       <paper-icon-button icon="clear" on-click="toggleSettings"></paper-icon-button>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.settings {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          height: 100%;
          background: grey;
          position: fixed;
          right: -130px;
          transition: transform 0.5s;
          color: white; 
        }

.settingsMove {
    transform: translate(-130px);
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-app-list-element',
      properties: {
      },

      toggleSettings : function() {
          this.$.edit.classList.toggle('settingsMove');
      },

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I dont think that code is working properly, I'm not sure what it is but this just prints to the screen. }//]]>

Comment: this is working for me. Tried at home (i am using Polymer 2.0).

Comment: If you have selected one settings panel... when you select another, does the first panel close by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

this.$.edit.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;'); 
(This is just an example. But you may re-style your element and define new css rules.